# Gatling run scenario in parallel

Tags: scala, performance, testing, gatling

I do some API Testing with Gatling right now. I am facing a problem regarding running scenarios in Parallel. I need to set up one User which needs to run the same scenario 100 times. But the 100 scenarios needs to be startet at once and run in parallel.

Does anyone have an idea, how this could be done ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I need to set up one User which needs to run the same scenario 100 times.

That's not how things work with Gatling.
Instead, you want to start 100 users at the same time, each going through the scenario in parallel. `atOnceUsers(100)`.

Comment: Yeah thats how I do it right now, but thats just a workaround for me because it does not fit my usecase in reality. 

Basically, its not possible to let one user run the same scenario 100 times parallel ?

Comment: I think what you're calling a scenario doesn't match Gatling's definition. A scenario is the unique workflow a given virtual user goes through.

Comment: But no, Gatling doesn't let virtual users execute parallel actions atm, with the exception of HTTP resources (https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#resources).

Comment: Maybe explaining your use case would help helping you.

Comment: Yes of course, so the API I want to test is used for an application we are developing. There are different products and the user can get some calculated information about these products from our application. In a specific usecase, one user can send multiple products to calculate (100 in total). These are send at once to our API and so one. Thats what I wanted to test. One user should send these 100 different Request at once. I didnt want to send 100 users to execute 1 scenario, because thats not how its done in reality. Did you get it ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to design your API this way? You should provide a batching API so your users can query the 100 products at once, instead of requesting them to flood your application with hundreds of requests.

Comment: Anyway, you can't do that with Gatling, sorry.

Comment: Yes, one user sends 100 products at once. Thats done because of some background work which requires that behaviour. So one request is one product.